# Python - Scraping API and Transform Json Data to CSV

Tags: python, json

My experience:
Just started with Python and no developer

My Goal:
Trying to scrape Sofascore API for getting Soccer Lineups to CSV. The json data need to be transformed. Final Output should be "Player Name", "substitute" and "avgRating". Also creating a loop for scraping multiple Lineups. ("https://api.sofascore.com/api/v1/event/xxxxxx/lineups")

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from io import StringIO
import json
import codecs

url = "https://api.sofascore.com/api/v1/event/9576298/lineups"
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0"}
r= requests.get(url, headers=headers)
json = r.json()

# Show json
print (json)
```

So having this data from one lineup, I don't understand how to transform this data to my goal. Any advice to put me in the right direction would be awesome!

Comment: why is the `import pandas as pd`? appears not used

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work for one lineup

```
import requests
import csv

# Get the data from API
url = r"https://api.sofascore.com/api/v1/event/9576298/lineups"
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0"}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
json_data = r.json()

# Load the lists of players from the scrapped json data
home_players_json = json_data["home"]["players"]
away_players_json = json_data["away"]["players"]


# Open a new file as our CSV file
with open("players.csv", "w", newline='') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

    # Add a header
    csv_writer.writerow(["Player Name", "Substitute", "avgRating"])

    # Combine the list of home players and away player inside a tuple...
    # ...to iterate through both of them with less code!
    for players_lists in (home_players_json, away_players_json):

        # Iterate through each player's data
        for player in players_lists:

            # Add each player's data to a row
            csv_writer.writerow([
                player["player"]["name"],
                player["substitute"],
                player["avgRating"]
            ])
```

For multiple lineups, you may need more data checking because some lineups don't provide a *substitute* or *avgRating* values for all players.

Also, some of the imports you used aren't actually needed.